# setOnCheckedChangeListener is getting invoked everytime the view is built

Tags: java, android

I have a class `Devices` that stores the checked state of the Switch using `setChecked(boolean)` and gets it by the `isChecked()` method.

Using this, I'm saving the state of the switch once once it is toggled.

But, if I change the state of a switch to ON, every time I scroll down and up back to the switch, `setOnCheckedChangeListener` is invoked. How do I prevent this?

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        DeviceHolder holder = null;
        Devices devices = list.get(position);
        String id = devices.id;

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new DeviceHolder();
        holder.devTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.devdesc);
        holder.nameTxt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.devname);
        holder.toggleSwitch = (Switch) row.findViewById(R.id.toggleswitch);
        holder.txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.debug);
        final int i=id;

        final Switch tswitch = holder.toggleSwitch;
        holder.toggleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                      //Comes here every time I scroll to a button that is ON
                        Control._service.write(i);
                        list.get(position).setChecked(tswitch.isChecked());
                    }
                });

        holder.devTxt.setText(devices.dev);
        holder.nameTxt.setText(devices.name);
        holder.txt.setText(id);
        if (tswitch.isChecked() != devices.isChecked())
            holder.toggleSwitch.setChecked(devices.isChecked());

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: You are initializing the listener in the getView() method which will be invoked each time you view is shown to the user. Do it somewhere else.

Comment: but I need to use the variables `i`, `position` and `tswitch`. How can I do it outside the getView?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it? If you are not going to initialize the OnCheckedChangeListener for the currently created View by getView then when you are going to toggle this switch there won't be a listener to react to this change.

Comment: But the problem is, `Control._service.write(i);` sends a signal to the microcontroller whether to turn ON or OFF. So if the switch is turned ON, it will send a signal to microcontroller to turn ON the corresponding pin. Not only that, every time you scroll to it, even though there is no change in the state of the switch (its still ON) it will send an ON signal again.